Python Ram Issues After PC Power Loss
Following a PC crash (power outage), my programs, which were running fine before the crash, have started acting up with a Memory Error on the console. This error only happens when I launch the program in a console instead of in Spyder. The only thing that occurred from when it was working to when it wasn't was the power outage.
I've tried reinstalling python from scratch, done a RAM test to see if there are any issues and given the .py executable admin rights in the event it was some reason limiting itself there.
All programs were running fine before and use multithreading. Wondering if anyone has ever had these issues before. I've gone through many of the questions on here to see if there are any solutions, but it seems to be a "Bad RAM" or people saying python is running in 32-bit (hence why I reinstalled it even though it was working fine until the restart). If the RAM was going bad then surely it would effect more than just the python console? It would cause errors in Spyder too.
Anyone had these issues before and how I can fix this?
Thank you!

"This error only happens when I launch the program in a console instead of in Spyder" sounds like you have two versions of python installed

@MarcoF. Extremely strange how that could cause it to crash with a memory error but after doing some digging you are right. Found the Anaconda python that was installed and launched it using that. It works fine with no memory errors. I'm still confused how that was the problem, especially that it all happened after a power outage, but extremely grateful none the less! Thank you!

"This error only happens when I launch the program in a console instead of in Spyder" sounds like you have two versions of python installed –
Marco F.
Commented on the original question.
After looking into it, having Spyder and a standalone python version on the same PC tends to cause issues.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
